# Resizing/compressing images for Google AMP?

Tags: performance, mobile, pagespeed, amp-html

I haven't been able to find any definitive answer to this question, but how important is it to provided dynamically sized images on AMP pages?

Google caches all AMP pages, including most of their resources. Coupled with the fact that they require dimensions to be defined for pretty much every amp-element, I expect that Google is doing some intelligent image compression when caching and only serving resources that are the appropriate size for the requesting device.

Can anyone verify this or otherwise? Should I be compressing/resizing my images to the minimum required or should I let Google do their magic here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AMP Supports srcset and size.
Let the browser choice the image.
The given size is for the ratio only. Eq you can say with=16 hight=9, but I use the size of the hiRes picture.

Comment: Ah, this is true. I was confusing srcset with sizes in thinking that it was only style related and didn't serve different images. So, the handling is on us then to serve the smallest filesize to the client. Thanks, Lovntola.